# Help with $C\cos(\omega t+\phi )=\Re{\Big\{De^{i\omega t}\Big\}}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I have a question regarding the following form
\begin{align}
x(t)&=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin (\omega t)\tag 1\\
&=C\cos(\omega t+\phi )\tag 2\\
&=\Re{\Big\{De^{i\omega t}\Big\}}\tag 3\\
&=\Re{\Big\{Ee^{i(\omega t+\phi)} \Big\}} \tag  4
\end{align}

For a complex number $z=a+ib$ I know I can write
\begin{align}
z=a+ib=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\phi} =\lvert z\rvert e^{i\phi} \tag 5
\end{align}

**Question:**

I guess I have $D=Ce^{i\phi}$? 
Should I compare this with equation $(5)$, so I actully have
$$
D=a+ib=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\phi}=Ce^{i\phi}=\lvert D\rvert e^{i\phi} \tag 6
$$
So $C=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\lvert D\rvert$? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is correct. Let $cos(\phi) = A/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ and $sin(\phi) = -B/\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$

then $x(t) =\sqrt{A^2+B^2}[cos(\omega t)cos(\phi) - sin(\omega t)sin(\phi)]$

$ = \sqrt{A^2+B^2}cos(\omega t + \phi)$

$= \Re{\Big\{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}e^{i(\omega t + \phi)} \Big\}} $. Let $C=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$.

$= \Re{\Big\{Ce^{i(\omega t + \phi)} \Big\}} = \Re{\Big\{Ce^{i\phi}e^{i(\omega t )} \Big\}} = \Re{\Big\{De^{i(\omega t )} \Big\}}  $

So $D= Ce^{i\phi}$, and

$C = |C|= |D| = \sqrt{A^2+B^2} $.

Comment: Great! Because $D$ is a complex number, does it also mean we can write $D=A+iB$? So we have $$D=A+iB=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}e^{i\phi}=Ce^{i\phi}=\lvert D\rvert e^{i\phi},$$ where $A=C\cos\phi$, $B=-C\sin\phi$ and $\phi=\arctan(-\frac{B}{A})$? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. Using the same notations I used for answering, 

$D=Ce^{i\phi}=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}[cos(\phi)+isin(\phi)]=A-iB$.

Comment: Thanks! One last question. What is $E$ in my equation no. $(4)$? Isn't $E=C$?

Comment: Yes. $E=C$. I tried editing it, but since it was less than 6 characters, I couldn't do it.